# use controller method from model class in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model

In my cakephp project, I use afterSave() method of a model class. In this method, I want to call another method that is located in app_controller file.

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

        var $name = 'MyModel';

        function afterSave($created) {

            $this->MyController->updateData();          
        }

}
```

Here updateData() is located in app_controller file, which is extended by MyController controller.

The above code does not work, so how can i actually call updateData() in this case..

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: MVC best-practice states that models shouldn't be aware of controllers. Should you not move the `updateData()` method to the model layer (ie. AppModel).

Comment: thanks deizel, I guess I should follow MVC guidelines, and I have changed my code doing away with using afterSave method.. thanks for proper guidance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is strongly NOT recommended but it can be done anyway... You should try as deizel says and move that method to AppModel or any other particular model...

you may use this function

App::import() check the [book here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/937/Loading-Controllers) to see how to use it

in your example:

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

        var $name = 'MyModel';

        function afterSave($created) {
            App::import('Controller', 'My');
            $something = new MyController;
            $something->updateData();          
        }

}
```

This is the correct way to load a class inside another place where it shouldn't be... Still you may use include or required and create an instance of the class since this is php.

Comment: thanks, but I would rather go with your recommendation of not following this approach, and so I will not use afterSave in this case.