# Saving data from a Cake3 entity

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

I'm stuggling to save data to my database from an entity method and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I have a method which provides me with a virtual field that shows how much time is left on an offer. This works fine for displaying the value. I would like to extend this so that when the remaining time is 0 a staus field is changed from 1 to 4 to indicate it's expired.

This is what I have so far it seems to work but the status value does not seem to save after being set.

This function works for showing the remaining time

```
protected function _getRemaining(){
    if($this->status === 1 || $this->status === 'Live'){
        // Get various timestamps
        $now = strtotime(Time::now());
        $created = strtotime($this->created);
        $duration = $this->duration;

        // Get the time remaining
        $remaining = (($created + $duration) - $now);

        // If below 0 set the value to 0
        if($remaining < 0){
            $remaining = 0;
            $this->_setStatusAuto(4);
        }
    } else {
        $remaining = 0;
    }
    return $remaining;
}
```

Here is where I am trying to change the status value. It returns the correct value but the database value is not changing!

```
protected function _setStatusAuto($level){
    $this->set('status', $level);
    return $this->status;
}
```

Any nudge in the right direction will be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->set('status', $level);
```

is used to send data from the controller to the view, not the model/database. You'll want to use the methods described here:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html

Comment: While you might be right on that the OP needs to actually save the data,  `set` is a method of the base entity class/trait.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you mean. I'm new myself to CakePHP myself, and am mostly browsing this section to see if I can help out and get some expirience. Care to explain "base entity class/trait?"

Comment: @Berry I've read through the docs at book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html. Unless I'm missing something it all seems to be aimed at saving things from the controller. I can't find anything about saving from the model/entity. Although I think you are right about `$this->set`

Comment: @ndm Your right that what I want to do is save the data. Is this possible to do from an Entity class?

Comment: Then wouldn't you just be able to call $this->save(); instead of $this->{Model name}->save(); ? Edit: I see Kuldeep gave you the same suggestion. Might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598675/use-controller-method-from-model-class-in-cakephp and see if you can make a save method in your controller, then call it from your model?

Comment: @Berry That was one of the first things i tried. It throws this `Error: Call to undefined method App\Model\Entity\Offer::save() ` also svaing from the controller is no problem but it will be a lot more elegent to have each offer take care of it's own expiry without having to involve the controllers

Comment: The way that error addresses the method makes it seem like it's looking for a method inside of the model, and still not in the controller (Otherwise it'd say something like OffersController, right?). Could this be the case?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way for the model to update itself when `_getRemaining()` returns 0. So offers can expire themselves when their duration has reached 0. This is all hapening in an Entity class.

Comment: Alright so I am absolutely not an authority on this matter, but wouldn't a function like that be more suited for a controller? I believe a model/entity class is only made for verification of in/outgoing data, where as a controller is designed to edit data, and send it back to the view/model. Maybe @ndm could shine some light on that, as he seems to be more experienced on the matter.

Comment: Yes maybe, but offers are grabbed by many functions and also loaded within associations by other controllers. To perform the check from within the controllers I'd have to check each offers remaining time then set the status everywhere where an offer was pulled out. Having the offers basicly check themselves whenever an offer entity is created seems like a better solution. All I can think is if i can create `getters` in the model then I should also be able to create `setters` also. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree, but it seems logical. I am kinda hoping @ndm stops by again =)

Comment: @KevWilson It seems that you don't know how saving data is ment to work, entities are dumb data containers, they don't save data, table objects do. I'd suggest that you study the docs on that topic: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html**.

Comment: @ndm Thanks a lot `entities are dumb data containers` is what I needed to hear. I got carried away with this line of thought. The virtual field worked so well it seemed logical to try and bolt more functionality onto it. I'll look into other ways of setting the status based off the result from `remaining`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First create object of model than set attributes after that

---

**$model->save();**

---

Comment: Interesting suggestion, so I can create a model object from within the model?